# Convergence of Linear First-Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $u$ is a twice continuously differentiable function with linear growth, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u'(x)-\frac{1}{g(x)} u(x) = 0 $$ 
and $g$ is a Lipschitz continuous function with Lipschitz constant $L<1$.

Consider the first order linear homogenous differential equation
$$y'(x)- \frac{1}{g(x)} y(x) = 0 .$$
The general solution is 
$$y(x)=c \exp\left(\int \frac{1} {g(x)} dx\right)$$
for constant $c \in \mathbb R$. In any solution with linear growth, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y(x)=0$.

Is it possible to conclude that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}u(x)=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "a solution with linear growth? Do you mean y(x)=O(x)?

Comment: yes i mean y(x) is O(x)

Answer (score 0):

If we only consider the limit

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u'(x)-\frac{1}{g(x)}\, u(x) = 0
$$
and impose conditions $\,u \in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb R),\,$ $\,u(x) = O(x),\,$ and $g$ – Lipschitz continuous with $\,L<1$, then the answer is **no**, we cannot conclude that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}u(x)=0.
$$

Counterexample:
set $u(x) = 2x$, and $g(x) = x$. 
Then all conditions are satisfied, 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u'(x)-\frac{1}{g(x)} u(x) 
= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(2-\frac{1}{x} 2x\right) 
= 0,
$$
and yet
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x) = \infty.
$$